# Facebook comment box error - don't understand debugger message

Tags: facebook

I am not an expert at this kind of stuff so just wanted to ask what the following error means?

Object at URL 'http://www.lanternghosttours.com/?from_fb=1' of type 'website' is invalid because the given value 'lanternghosttours' for property 'fb:admins' could not be parsed as type 'fbid'.

All I want is to be able to moderate comments.
I created the app & use the code generator and only when I add the href 'www.lanternghosttours.com' it suddenly removes the moderation options on the top of the commentbox.

What have I done wrong or am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The `fb:admins` tag needs to be a user ID of a user - you've put the username of a page

Put the user ID of a user there instead, or the create an app, and use the app ID in a `fb:app_id` tag instead

Comment: Thank you lgy,however while understand what you are saying I have tried adding both <meta property="fb:admins" content="{509062047}"> and <meta property="fb:app_id" content="{256833794419931}"> ontop of the script. This is the code i have pasted and embedded into my site (i know it is messy). Can you let me know what I am missing here? I will paste the code into a seperate message, thanks. the

Comment: <meta property="fb:app_id" content="{256833794419931}">
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1">
</script>

<body>
<meta property="fb:admins" content="{509062047}">
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="https://www.lanternghosttours.com" data-num-posts="5" data-width="890" data-colorscheme="dark"></div>

Comment: Why are there '{'s around the IDs? that's not necessary - otherwise that looks like it should be OK, what is the debugger saying with those tags?